How can we leverage API to bulk upload File Links with relation to parent records
We are trying to leverage Bulk API to upload File Links
We create an Bulk API ingest job using the following URL:
https://{{Domain}}/services/data/v59.0/jobs/ingest

and Body:
{
  "object" : "ContentVersion",
  "externalIdFieldName" : "Id",
  "contentType" : "CSV",
  "operation" : "upsert"
}

Then we upload batches using the following URL:
https://{{Domain}}/services/data/v59.0/jobs/ingest/{{jid}}/batches

and Body:
Title,ContentUrl,ContentDocument.Parent.UrlName
Test,https://google.com/,A-00001
Test,https://google.com/,A-00002

When we get ingest job results using GET https://{{Domain}}/services/data/v59.0/jobs/ingest/{{jid}}
we get the following result:

{
    "id": "750D4000007fN2tIAE",
    "operation": "upsert",
    "object": "ContentVersion",
    "createdById": "005Hp00000iQJrXIAW",
    "createdDate": "2024-04-23T11:43:07.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2024-04-23T11:43:34.000+0000",
    "state": "Failed",
    "externalIdFieldName": "Id",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 59.0,
    "jobType": "V2Ingest",
    "lineEnding": "LF",
    "columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": 0,
    "numberRecordsFailed": 0,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": 0,
    "apiActiveProcessingTime": 0,
    "apexProcessingTime": 0,
    "errorMessage": "InvalidBatch : Field name not found : ContentDocument.Parent.UrlName"
}

My colleague told me to use FirstPublishLocationId instead of ContentDocument.ParentId.
When I change the data to the following format
Title,ContentUrl,FirstPublishLocation.UrlName
Test,https://google.com/,A-00001
Test,https://google.com/,A-00002

we receive another error

{
    "id": "750D4000007fN2yIAE",
    "operation": "upsert",
    "object": "ContentVersion",
    "createdById": "005Hp00000iQJrXIAW",
    "createdDate": "2024-04-23T11:47:02.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2024-04-23T11:47:21.000+0000",
    "state": "Failed",
    "externalIdFieldName": "Id",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 59.0,
    "jobType": "V2Ingest",
    "lineEnding": "LF",
    "columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": 0,
    "numberRecordsFailed": 0,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": 0,
    "apiActiveProcessingTime": 0,
    "apexProcessingTime": 0,
    "errorMessage": "InvalidBatch : type must be specified for polymorphic foreign key field: FirstPublishLocation"
}

Is there any way how can this be done?

We can use the following body for the request, assuming we haven't published any parent article yet, so that only one record exists with a given UrlName
Title,ContentUrl,Knowledge__kav:FirstPublishLocation.UrlName
test1,"https://support.usa.canon.com/resources/sites/CANON/content/live/FAQS/100000/FAQ100562/en_US/LK-72 User's Guide.pdf",ART100001
test2,"https://support.usa.canon.com/resources/sites/CANON/content/live/FAQS/100000/FAQ100562/en_US/LK-72 User's Guide.pdf",ART100001

